# How to create a Windows 2008 Advanced Firewall rules group definition through the command prompt

Tags: windows, firewall, scripting, command-line-interface

Is there a way to create a group, or add to an existing group, to a rule in Windows Advanced Firewall (preferable through a command prompt or WSH script).

**Edit:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution for this old question that has also been bugging me for a long time!

The [New-NetFirewallRule](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554908(v=wps.630).aspx) TechNet article states this about the `-Group` parameter of the New-NetFirewallRule commandlet:

> [...] This
>   parameter specifies the source string for the DisplayGroup parameter.
>   [...] Rule groups can be used to
>   organize rules by influence and allows batch rule modifications. Using
>   the Set-NetFirewallRule cmdlets, if the group name is specified for a
>   set of rules or sets, then all of the rules or sets in that group
>   receive the same set of modifications. It is a good practice to
>   specify this parameter value with a universal and world-ready indirect
>   @FirewallAPI name.
>
> ***Note***: The DisplayGroup parameter cannot be specified upon object
>   creation using the New-NetFirewallRule cmdlet, but can be modified
>   using dot-notation and the Set-NetFirewallRule cmdlet.

That sounds like there's a chance, right? While trying to find out how to do this myself, I ran the following:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Core Networking - IPv6 (IPv6-In)" | Get-Member
```

...and noted that the `DisplayGroup` property only has a Get method, but the `Group` property (with its `RuleGroup` alias) has both a Get and a Set method.

**The PowerShell solution is as-follows:**

Thanks to @maoizm, this solution now works when 1 or more rules with the same DisplayName exist:

```
$RuleName = "NameOfYourFirewallRuleGoesHere"
$RuleGroup = "YourGroupNameGoesHere"
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $RuleName | ForEach { $_.Group = '$RuleGroup'; Set-NetFirewallRule -InputObject $_ }
```

And this will actually create a new group name that is assigned to your rule.

**Note**: The `netsh` command does not have an `add group` command. See the syntax for [Netsh AdvFirewall Firewall Commands](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd734783(v=ws.10).aspx) here.

Comment: As DisplayName isn't required to be unique the second command fails if you have more that 1 rule. The following one-liner works when 1 or more rules with the same DisplayName exist: `Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'GTA V' | ForEach { $_.Group = 'games'; Set-NetFirewallRule -InputObject $_  }`

Answer (score 6):

Rules in the Windows Firewall can be bundle together and activated or deactivated as a group.

With `netsh advfirewall` command you can add rules to the Firewall. Use the switch `group=` for manage the AdvFirewall groups.

Use something like this:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule profile=domain group="Remote Desktop" new enable=Yes
```

Comment: Thank you. But, that tells me how to change an existing group. I want to know how to either add a group, or put one of my rules in an existing group.

Comment: With this commmand (Netsh advfirewall firewall set) you can create or change and existing rule and move it from its group. This works for what you need. Try it.

Comment: Alright, so what's the syntax for creating a new group? I tried: `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule Group="SmarterTools Administrative Interfaces" new` and receive the error 'No rules match the specified criteria'

Comment: @RicardoPolo, sorry to tellyou, but the command to add a rule is netsh advFirewall firewall add rule...  but none of the modifiers of this command allows to create a Group

Comment: @RicardoPolo I am sorry to confirm that this command doesn't allow to create new rule group

Answer (score 5):

While you specifically mention

> ... through the command prompt

I'm gonna assume you mean using a script.  With 2008, you can use powershell.  Its pretty straightforward:

```
function Add-FirewallRule {
   param( 
      $name,
      $tcpPorts,
      $appName = $null,
      $serviceName = $null
   )
    $fw = New-Object -ComObject hnetcfg.fwpolicy2 
    $rule = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.FWRule

    $rule.Name = $name
    if ($appName -ne $null) { $rule.ApplicationName = $appName }
    if ($serviceName -ne $null) { $rule.serviceName = $serviceName }
    $rule.Protocol = 6 #NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP
    $rule.LocalPorts = $tcpPorts
    $rule.Enabled = $true
    $rule.Grouping = "@firewallapi.dll,-23255"
    $rule.Profiles = 7 # all
    $rule.Action = 1 # NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW
    $rule.EdgeTraversal = $false

    $fw.Rules.Add($rule)
}

# Sample Usage
Add-FirewallRule "Test port 1234" "1234" $null $null
Add-FirewallRule "Test port 5555-6666" "5555-6666" $null $null
Add-FirewallRule "Test port 2222 Calc" 2222 "c:\windows\system32\calc.exe" $null
Add-FirewallRule "Test port 3333 W3SVC" 3333 $null "W3SVC"
```

See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2010/11/07/adding-a-windows-firewall-rule-using-powershell/) for more detail...

Comment: Windows 8 introduced native PowerShell cmdlets for managing Windows Firewall (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554906(v=wps.630).aspx); however, since this question is specifically about Windows Server 2008, your answer is likely the only option (apart from using `netsh`).

Answer (score 1):

The `netsh` command line does not have a flag for this.

As an alternative to the PowerShell solutions above, the group name is part of the registry hive.

In fact, the `.wfw` Firewall export is actually a [raw `regf` registry hive](https://github.com/libyal/libregf/blob/master/documentation/Windows%20NT%20Registry%20File%20(REGF)%20format.asciidoc).  If you import this into the registry editor, you can see that it's a list of `REG_SZ` pipe-delimited values.

Custom values are located at

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules
```

Here's a snapshot of a Google Chrome firewall entry (newlines added for readability)

```
{7E29D2BA-3EBF-4AFD-BF6E-BA6486C74660}

v2.10|
Action=Allow|
Active=TRUE|
Dir=In|
Protocol=17|
LPort=5353|
App=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe|
Name=Google Chrome (mDNS-In)|
Desc=Inbound rule for Google Chrome to allow mDNS traffic.|
EmbedCtxt=Google Chrome|
```

The "Group" is stored under `EmbedCtxt` and its value is `Google Chrome`.

... so one could assume that you can manipulate the registry value using the same technique...

1. Find the registry entry

   ```
   reg query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\FirewallRules /f "Google Chrome"
   ```
2. Overwrite the registry entry with a new/different value `...|EmbedCtx=My Custom Group|`
   **Note #1:** Code intentionally omitted since appending to an existing registry value using command prompt [is very tricky](https://superuser.com/a/607582/443147).

   **Note #2:** Without the trailing `|`, the value will be ignored.

[image]